# How can two sets that do not intersect, be a subset of one?

Tags: probability

How can two sets that do not intersect, be a subset of one?

$$
C_{1},C_{2} \subset l
$$
$$
C_{1} \cap C_{2} = \emptyset
$$
$$
C_{1} \subset C_{2}
$$

Specifically I am looking at the theorem that states the following:

If $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ are subsets of $l$ such that $C_{1}$ $\subset$ $C_{2}$ then $P(C_{1}) \leq P(C_{2})$

Where $P(C_{1})$ and $P(C_{2})$ are probability set function.

But one of the definition for a probability set function is that no two sets have a point in common.

Comment: Your definition for the probability set function is incorrect.

Comment: If $C_1=\emptyset$ then both conditions hold.

Comment: If $A \subset B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then it must be that $A = \emptyset$.  I don't think the definition os probability of set function requires no two sets have a point in common.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding part of the definition correctly.

$P(C_{1} \cup C_{2} \cup C_{3} \cup \ldots) = P(C_{1}) + P(C_{2}) + P(C_{3}) + \ldots $ such that no two sets have a point in common

Is one of the definition in my book.

Comment: That's not a definition.  Thats a formula that you can use for disjoint sets.  It presumes the sets are disjoint.  For sets that are not disjoint you have to use a different formula.  One that uses the exclusion principal.  From memory I think it is $P(C_1 \cup C_2) = P(C_1) + P(C_2) - P(C_1 \cap C_2)$.

Comment: No, @Rany .  The definition is that *when* none of the sets have a point in common, *then* $\mathsf P(\bigcup_i C_i) = \sum_i \mathsf P(C_i)$ and *vice versa*.  It does not mean that sets have to be disjoint to have a probability measure; just that if there are intersections then the measure of the union *is not* the sum of their measures.

Comment: Where did you come across the definition.  In what you quoted it specifically says it only applies to disjoint sets.  It doesn't say all sets are disjoint.  Just if they aren't you can't use it.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  to elaborate.  This formula is for specific conditions.  When the conditions are not met (i.e. the sets aren't disjoint) you can't use *that* formula to find the probabilities.   It doesn't mean the probabilities don't exist other wise.

Comment: This definition is found in the book Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by Hogg and Craig.

Comment: @GrahamKemp This makes a lot more sense if that is the case. But for some reason my book tries to indicate that is one of the criteria for a probability set function.

Comment: That was the definition for disjoint sets.  That doesn't mean probabilities can not exist for non disjoint sets.  It be absurd to think that.  Obviously the probability of someones name being "alfred" exist and obviously the probability someones name begins with "A" must exist.  You just can't use this formula to find them.

Comment: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=lyba9dptxcwojo0ddlua.png

Comment: @Rany. It is a property of a probability set function that it works *that* way under *these* conditions.  It does not mean *these* conditions are the only ones it can works under; just that it might work differently then.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Okay, that makes  sense, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @fleablood I linked a screenshot of what was written in my book. I read it as those were explicit definitions and a probability set function could only be defined as that. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I see.  I'd interpret this (after five minutes reading) as saying that you don't *have* a probability set function for subsets.

Comment: @fleablood Is that the case? Here is the theorem they talk about written in the book.

http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=3v808u51wg6pem1yyoek.png

Comment: @fleablood Ok I understand now I think. part (b) is more a property of probability set functions? And not actually a strict definition for something to be defined as a probability set function?

Comment: I only glanced through your scans but here's my interpretation:  The expression P(C) exists.  For $A \subset C$ P(A) and P(A) < P(C) exists.  But  P(C) is the probability set function of the output of *some* experiment and P(A) is the probability set function of the output of *another* experiment.  However they can not both be probability set functions of the *same* experiment.  But for A, C-A, and $(C \cup A)^c$ one can have P(A), P(C-A) and P((C U A)^c) can be the probability set functions of the same experiment.  But to be honest I'm not entirely sure I understand the definition....

Comment: .... I think is merely a way of turning *any* function P: sets -> Reals to make P(C) a *probability*.  You need it to be part of a group of things to make a 100% probability.  Once you define it *as* a Probability you can work with it.

Comment: Ack! No!  Now I get it!.  The $C_i$ that defined the probability space are *different* from the $C$ in the theorem.  You can use $C_1, C_2....$ to create the space and $C_i \cap C_j = \empty set$.  But now we can use the $C_i$ to create a bunch of new sets $D_i$ that are *not* nescessarily disjoint.  Example: A = $C_1 \cup C_2$ and P(A) = P(C1) + P(C2) and B = $C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$ and P(B) = P(C1) + P(C2) + P(C3) but A and B are *not* any of the original $C_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been given the property that *when* $\{C_i\}$ are disjoint (aka mutually exclusive, or "no two have common elements") *then* $\mathsf P(\bigcup_i C_i)=\sum_i \mathsf P(C_i)$, and *vice versa*.   That is:

$$\mathsf P(C_1\cup C_2\cup \ldots) = \mathsf P(C_1)+\mathsf P(C_2)+\ldots$$

*When and only when* the sets have no common points.

---

You are now exploring *what happens* when the sets are *not* disjoint.

When $C_1\subseteq C_2$ then while $C_1$ and $C_2$ are *clearly not* disjoint, we can divide $C_2$ itself into two *disjoint* subsets, $C_1$ and $C_2\setminus C_1$.   (That is the set difference symbol.   Your book *may* just use "$-$").

Thus: $C_2 = C_1\cup (C_2\setminus C_1)$ and since these subsets *are* disjoint, we have: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(C_1)+\mathsf P(C_2\setminus C_1)~=~&\mathsf P(C_1\cup (C_2\setminus C_1))\\ =~& \mathsf P(C_2)\end{align}$$

Now another property of the function you should have is that it is always *at least* zero.   (That is, non-negative.)   So we know: $\mathsf P(C_1)\leq \mathsf P(C_1)+\mathsf P(\textsf{anything})$

This gives us that *when* $C_1\subseteq C_2$ then: $$\mathsf P(C_1) ~\leq~ \mathsf P(C_2)$$

$\Box$

---

**PS:** Note that the converse is not necessarily true.